# Update commit message, Author and commiter after push

Tags: git, github

I am trying to fix a bug in one of the github repo and I got an comment saying I should change three things. Not exactly sure how to do that in clean manner without screwing up thing. 
https://github.com/prestodb/presto/pull/11290

Is there any way I can update the following three things after I pushed the commit.

- Author
- Commiter
- git commit message

I know I can use **rebase interactive** to change the commit message and then **force push** it. 
However, would it create any issue for **Pull Request?** for Github. How to update commitor and Author?

Answer (score 1):

Going by the suggestion in the feedback, you might get away with just running this:

```
git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>"
```

This would let you change the author of the latest commit, about which your reviewer is complaining, to match the committer.  Then, you may change the commit message via:

```
git commit --amend -m 'New Commit Message'
```

After you have fixed the author and message, you would force push your branch to GitHub via something like:

```
git push --force origin master
```

You should *not* have to do a formal interactive rebase here, if the commit in question sits on the very top of your branch.  If you can get away with `git commit --amend`, then happily do so, because an interactive rebase is a lot more complex than this.

Comment: after `amend` I can see that my author has updated and I have an option to update the commit message. However it doesn't update the `commiter`. I can see `Committer` has not updated in `gitk`

Comment: OK...I was wondering about this.  Are you saying that both the author _and_ committer were wrong?  I was thinking that maybe one was right, and the other was out of sync.

Comment: I can see both are same in github `Gaurang Shah authored and Gaurang Shah committed 23 hours ago`, not exactly sure what commenter is suggesting actually.  I think it's an email address which is not matching with my github account. in both, author and commiter.

Comment: Well, the first thing you need to do is figure out which author and email the owner of the branch wants you to be using.  The first part of my answer should fix the author part of the problem.  Not sure about the committer.

Answer (score 0):

Tim's Answer above help me update the **last commit message** and **Author's name** and **Email**.

However, Commiters details was not updated, I did the following and I can see commiters email and name updated as well.

Commiters details are being taken from your `git config`, so you need to update that before you make changes in commit message.

**Update Git Config**

```
git config user.name <user name>
git config user.email <user email>
```

After this use the following command as suggest by Tim,

```
git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>"
```